# How do I alter contents of column B depending on the content of column A using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding

I have hard-coded a table with 4 columns (req, label, type, customise) where the number of rows is up to the user. In the "type" column there will be a select element with several options, and depending on the selected option the content displayed in the neighbouring "customise" column will change. The user can successfully add a new row to the table via JQuery.

I have managed to alter the contents of the "customise" column, however, regardless of how many rows the user adds, it will always change the contents of the first row.

I imagine the pseudocode to be something along the lines of:

```
if(rowID === 3)
{
  switch(rowID3.type)
  {
    case "dropdownbox":
      rowID3.columnID4.content = dropdown box
      break;
    case "radiobox":
      rowID3.columnID4.content = radio box
      break;
  }
}
```

To explain my pseudocode:

For a particular rowID, switch between the options within the select element, if the option is a dropdownbox then change the content of the neighbouring column to be a select element.

Previously I used:

```
    $(document).on('change', 'select[name="type"]', function()
    {
    console.log($(this).val())
    var selected = $(this).val();

switch(selected)
            {
                case "type":
                    break;
                case "header":
                    $('#customise' + count).empty();
                    $('#customise' + count).append('Header');
                    break;
```

Code for inserting new row:

```
$required = "<input type='checkbox' name='check' id='required" + count + "'>";
        $label = "<input type='text' placeholder='Enter your label' id='label" + count + "'></input>";
        $type = "<SELECT name='type' ><OPTION>Type</option><OPTION value='header'>Header</option><OPTION value='hr'>HR</option><OPTION value='textbox'>Text Box</option><OPTION value='datefield'>Date Field</option><OPTION value='person'>Person</option><OPTION value='dropdownbox'>Dropdown Box</option><OPTION value='image'>Image</option><OPTION value='checkboxgroup'>Checkbox Group</option><OPTION value='radiogroup'>Radio Group</option><option>" + count + "</option></select>";
        $values = "<span id='values" + count +"'";

        $element = "<tr class='child'> <td>" + $required + "</td> <td>" + $label + "</td> + <td>" + $type + "</td> <td>" + $values + "</td>";
```

**My question:** 
 How do I alter the contents of column B depending on the value of column A, where both of which are inserted through JQuery when the user clicks on the add button?

Comment: Dont alter the contents afterward. Instead, when you go to add the row, check the value there and and the cell content dynamically at that point

Comment: The row is added first, then the user customises. Would it be easier/better if the user customised the row, then it was added?

Comment: How do they start to customize a row, do they each have a button or something? Or are you changing the second column when the user changes the select in the first column or something like that?

Comment: They customise it by say, for example, wishing to have a dropdown box where they can enter as many values as they'd like for the dropdown box. If they want a text area, they cannot customise it. If they select an image, an input element for a source will be available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not entirely clear what you want to modify in the table or what should trigger the modification. But, the below should show you the concepts youd need to make it work.

Note that my table starts out with one row. On page load, that row is read and the html stored as a data attribute on the table itself then the row is removed. Later when the user clicks the button, the code makes a copy to the stored html and adds that ad the row. I find this approach to adding uniform dynamic content easier to manage than using string concatenation

```js
var $table = $('#my-table')
var $initialRow = $table.find('tbody tr:eq(0)');
$table.data('cloned-row', $initialRow[0].outerHTML);
$initialRow.remove();

$('.add').click(function() {
  $table.append($($table.data('cloned-row')))
});
$table.on('change', '[name="type"]', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var type = $this.val();
  var curRowIndex = $table.find('[name="type"]').index($this);
  var $curRow=$table.find('tbody tr').eq(curRowIndex);
  var $elementToModify = $curRow.find('td:eq(1)').find('input');
  switch (type) {
    case 'header':
      $elementToModify.css('background-color','red');
      break;
    case 'hr':
      $elementToModify.css('background-color','grey');
      break;
    case 'textbox':
      $elementToModify.css('background-color','teal');
      break;
    case 'datefield':
      $elementToModify.css('background-color','black');
      break;
    case 'person':
      $elementToModify.css('background-color','purple');
      break;
    case 'dropdownbox':
      $elementToModify.css('background-color','green');
      break;
    case 'image':
      $elementToModify.css('background-color','blue');
      break;
    case 'checkboxgroup':
      $elementToModify.css('background-color','chucknoris');
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info add">Add new row</button>

<table id="my-table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Required</td>
      <td>Label</td>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>Count</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your label" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <SELECT name="type">
          <OPTION>Select a type</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="header">Header</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="hr">HR</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="textbox">Text Box</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="datefield">Date Field</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="person">Person</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="dropdownbox">Dropdown Box</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="image">Image</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="checkboxgroup">Checkbox Group</OPTION>
          <OPTION value="radiogroup">Radio Group</OPTION>
          <option>count</option>
        </SELECT>
      </td>
      <td><span class="values"></span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you :) never knew of that method of adding rows, learn something new every day haha.

Comment: @looksgoodhoss If you ever work in php, another favorite of mine is to keep the row in a template file like `someTableRow.inc` (arbitrary suffix), use php to read the template file, then echo out the encoded html as an attribute on the table like `data-template-edit-group="<?php echo (isset($pageSections['group-template']) ? htmlspecialchars($pageSections['group-template']): '');?>"` Doing it this way, you have the data you need to make the clone already stored on the table before it is ever even served to the browser